# Background and Buttons for Login System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm heading to code a Login System for a game with my own costumization , I'm talking about buttons , image of the background and the login system itself .

Since I don't know how Login system personalization works I will ask here .

The Background of the Login Systems or the back page is a simple image that is resizeble with any resolution of the computer/options the user chose ?

Is it a simple image uploaded to it or it has anything else ?

And the costumized buttons is an image too , with functions ?

I'm scripting in Unity , so i will add code to an image(buttons) or it's something like windows form buttons ?

Comment: Just follow http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Basics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Background of the Login Systems or the back page is a simple image
>   that is resizeble with any resolution of the computer/options the user
>   chose ?

Yes it's possible,but you cannot use Animated Gifs.But you can try [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/AnimatedGifDrawer)

> Is it a simple image uploaded to it or it has anything else ? And the
>   costumized buttons is an image too , with functions ?

Just follow [Unity Official Tutorial on GUI Image](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-image)

Just simply

- go to>hierarchy>create>UI>Image
- Change source image>choose what you want

> I'm scripting in Unity , so i will add code to an image(buttons) or
>   it's something like windows form buttons ?

Yes,just like that.for an example,this is a sample script for main menu.You have to use "`using UnityEngine.UI`;" namespace. Create this in main canvas And drag those(play and exit)buttons for those public button objects.Change "image component's" source image.Create separate Quit menu like this.

[I referenced this tutorial,but you have to do minor changes though](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pT4uca2bSgc)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class menuScript : MonoBehaviour {
public Canvas quitMenu;
public Button startText;
public Button exitText;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    quitMenu=quitMenu.GetComponent<Canvas>();
    startText=startText.GetComponent<Button>();
    exitText=exitText.GetComponent<Button>();
    quitMenu.enabled=false;
    }

    public void ExitPress()
    {
        quitMenu.enabled=true;
        startText.enabled=false;
        exitText.enabled=false;
    }

    public void NoPress()
    {
        quitMenu.enabled=false;
        startText.enabled=true;
        exitText.enabled=true;
    }
    public void StartLevel()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(1);
    }
    public void ExitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot , it helped ^^

Comment: I'm glad that helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in Unity, then check out their GUI stuff. The UI tools they added in 4.6 will do everything you need in terms of the interface.

As for the actual login system, well that depends on what you're logging into...